# EWS 2016 requested version is Not Supported on Calnedard.bind using 2013_sp1 as Exchange version

Tags: vsto, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

I i was asked too make a Outlook addin with uses the  exchange server 2016 to syncronise entry from the database with the entrys  from the Appointments in the Outlook Calendar.
Problem now is that had to use the Exhangeversion of  2013_sp1 as ExchangeVersion with as far as i read is should be ok.
But by my colleage  the outlook plugin means that "Exchange Server doesn't support the requested version” on the try to start the  addin.  it comes up by the method CalendarFolder.Bind(m_service, folderId, new PropertySet()); 
as fas as could  read von the stacktrace.
I do not know  if it i just a type of authenfication problem or the problem by the  versions or how i call them

here my code `
m_service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

```
            m_service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //  NetworkCredentials 


            m_service.Url = new Uri(EWSServerUrl);
            FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
            CalendarFolder calendarESW = CalendarFolder.Bind(m_service, folderId, new PropertySet());`
```

i would be grateful for a bit of help ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the server that is responding to the request doesn't support the Requested Server version (Auto-discover can be used to check the supported EwsSupportedSchemas https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900154(v=exchg.150).aspx ). Mostly likely this is because the server that is responding is running a lower version of Exchange or CU version than what your requesting. You can easily check this by looking at the ServerVersion that is return in the response you getting eg check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.serverinfo(v=exchg.80).aspx or enable tracing and check the trace https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: it is a ews server 2016 so ic can'tt be too low but i will  check out if something is not supported on 2016